# How to use GloVe word embedding for non-English text

Tags: csv, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, glove

I am trying to run a GloVe word embedding on a `Bengali` news dataset. Now the original GloVe source doesn't have any supported language other than English but I found [this](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors) which has word vectors pretrained for 30 non-English languages.

I am running [this notebook on text classification  using GloVe embeddings](https://www.kaggle.com/stacykurnikova/using-glove-embedding). My question is

1. Can I use the pre-trained Bengali word vectors with my custom `Bengali` dataset, and run on this model?
2. [this pretrained Bengali word vector](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors) is in `tsv` format. Using the following code I cannot seem to parse it into `word-vector` lists.

   ```
    embeddings_index = {}
    f = open(root_path + 'bn.tsv')
    for line in f:
        values = line.split('\t')
        word = values[1] ## The first entry is the word
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32') ## These are the vecotrs representing the embedding for the word
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs
    f.close()

    print('GloVe data loaded')
   ```

and I get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-39-3a4cb8d8dfb0> in <module>()
          4     values = line.split('\t')
          5     word = values[1] ## The first entry is the word
    ----> 6     coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32') ## These are the vecotrs representing the embedding for the word
          7     embeddings_index[word] = coefs
          8 f.close()

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
         83 
         84     """
    ---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
         86 
         87 

    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'এবং'
```

Comment: '.tsv' is not the usual format for sharing trained word-vectors, so I'd be wary of any source providing vectors in that format. (And, your error suggests that a non-numeric string is still present in your `values[1:]` parameter. Are you sure the contents of `values` are what you expect?) If your main aim it to acquire reusable vectors, Facebook themselves have provided vectors in many languages, including Bengali, at https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

Comment: And, you don't necessarily need to provide your own parsing code, or store vectors in a raw Python dict. A library like `gensim` includes support classes for loading & working with pre-trained vectors in various formats.

Comment: Thanks. But do you know if GloVe has any non-English pretrained word vectors like this? I want to cover all of the pretrained word vectors available out there

Comment: Your search would be as good as mine on that issue. But most people who want to use pre-trained vectors just want the vectors to be useful, without caring too much about the technique used to train them. GloVe is a little harder to train on giant vocabularies, & doesn't have the OOV benefits of FastText. So I'm not sure what project *would* go through the same exercise, of pre-training comparable vectors across many languages, that Facebook has. So if you specifically need GloVE vectors for some evaluative purpose, you may need to train them yourself.